# Why is referencing `window.location` considered a bad practice?

Tags: angular

While building a shared library for internal use, which will be used by several teams for Angular applications. These applications will only run in the browser. I've used the code below to construct a `returnUrl` - to which a user returns after logging in with an external identity provider like Keycloak.

```js
private _iframeRedirectUri = `${window.location.origin} ... the rest of the url`;
```

In the PR I made, a co-worker made comments regarding `window.location.origin`. He stated that referencing the native web apis is considered a bad practice and I should use a library like `ng-web-apis` (https://github.com/ng-web-apis/) and getting the `location.origin` like this:

```js
private _iframeRedirectUri = `${this.location.origin} ... the rest of the url`;

constructor(@Inject(LOCATION) readonly location: Location) {}
```

When looking at the source code of ng-web-apis, the `LOCATION` token looks like this:

```js
export const LOCATION = new InjectionToken<Location>(
    'An abstraction over window.location object',
    {
        factory: () => inject(WINDOW).location,
    },
);

// And window:

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>(
    'An abstraction over global window object',
    {
        factory: () => {
            const {defaultView} = inject(DOCUMENT);

            if (!defaultView) {
                throw new Error('Window is not available');
            }

            return defaultView;
        },
    },
);
```

What's the point in this abstraction when these application will never run in a backend and *always* in the browser? Discussing this with my co-worker results in "it's just evil" and "never reference stuff like window or document", so that's not helping me *why*. Can anyone help me understand this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience - it is not good from a testing perspective. If you have actions that must change your routing data (as an example) - your tests will do the same and the page will reload once hit `window.location` change statement.

Declaring it as an injection token allows you to use dependency injection to instantiate proper `window` instance per use - for tests you can bind to mock object and to native window otherwise.

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: WINDOW, useValue: mockWindow}
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can not be sure what changes will be made to your application in the future. But I see at least 2 advantages of this approach

- [SSR](https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis)
- Much easier way to mock the browser API via DI in unit tests